# htaccess redirect language path to new a new path

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a language path to a new path with the same substructure as the original path.

My language structure looks like this

```
www.example.com/en
www.example.com/da
www.example.com/fi
```

Now I want to redirect the www.example.com/da to www.example.com/dk and also the www.example.com/fi to www.example.com/en

This is the code I have been struggled with.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(fi|da)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But this ends up in a loop with the index file and the path in the end.

```
http://www.example.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/index.php?path=da
```

Answer (score 0):

At last I found an answer to my question. This is how I did to redirect both com/da and com/fi to com/en.

```
RewriteRule ^(da|fi).*$ http://www.example.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```